# Unable to set HomePath And config in grafana

Tags: grafana

I am new to grafana and I am getting this error while executing the `grafana-server.exe`

> Grafana-server Init Failed: Could not find config defaults, make sure homepath command line parameter is set or working directory is homepath

Firstly, I am not clear about which path to specify as homepath and which to specify as config path.

Secondly, I have tried to set the homepath using this command:

```
grafana-cli admin reset-admin-password --homepath "c:\" mynewpassword
```

But getting this error :

> "Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -homepath"

Comment: This could be an incorrect installation. Haven't tried with windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

in grafana version 7.3.5 this is the help message.

```
NAME:
   Grafana CLI - A new cli application

USAGE:
   grafana-cli [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]

VERSION:
   7.3.5

AUTHOR:
   Grafana Project <hello@grafana.com>

COMMANDS:
   plugins  Manage plugins for grafana
   admin    Grafana admin commands
   help, h  Shows a list of commands or help for one command

GLOBAL OPTIONS:
   --pluginsDir value       Path to the Grafana plugin directory (default: "/var/lib/grafana/plugins") [$GF_PLUGIN_DIR]
   --repo value             URL to the plugin repository (default: "https://grafana.com/api/plugins") [$GF_PLUGIN_REPO]
   --pluginUrl value        Full url to the plugin zip file instead of downloading the plugin from grafana.com/api [$GF_PLUGIN_URL]
   --insecure               Skip TLS verification (insecure) (default: false)
   --debug                  Enable debug logging (default: false)
   --configOverrides value  Configuration options to override defaults as a string. e.g. cfg:default.paths.log=/dev/null
   --homepath value         Path to Grafana install/home path, defaults to working directory
   --config value           Path to config file
   --help, -h               show help (default: false)
   --version, -v            print the version (default: false)
```

so you can set it by passing --homepath .
be careful, it seems its diffrent with grafana-server parametes. in that case you must set flag with only 1 hyphen (-homepath)
but come back to your problem there is 2 things to say.

first is to order your command correctly. i mean something like this

```
grafana-cli --homepath path ...
```

because homepath flag is for grafana-cli so it must come right after that or there will not be any guarantee of "what you want to do is what you write".

second is the homepath. consider this tree directory

```
.
|_LICENSE
|_NOTICE.md
|_README.md
|_VERSION
|_bin
|_conf
|_data
|_plugin-bundled
|_public
|_scripts
```

here is installation directory or homepath which you must set. more specifically exacly around bin(or conf or data or ...) directory.